# problem : PHP Fatal error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket

Tags: php, mysql, fatal-error

I have a problem when i run my php code (**sometimes it runs successfully, but I need how to avoid it in future**)
the error appears as :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /home/myegyme/public_html/Connections/myegy.php on line 9
```

and "**/home/myegyme/public_html/Connections/myegy.php**" contains :

```
<?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"
$hostname_myegy = "localhost";
$database_myegy = "mydatabase";
$username_myegy = "myusername";
$password_myegy = "mypassword";
$myegy = mysql_pconnect($hostname_myegy, $username_myegy, $password_myegy) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```

How can I solve this problem?. please help me !

Answer (score 1):

add

```
[client]
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

to `my.cnf` as described on

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/762/solve-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmpmysqlsock/

Comment: the problem that I had no control on server which hosts my website, so I can not edit this file

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem once, when the socket was already in use (another program or database). Maybe that is the case, if you say that it runs sometimes.

Answer (score -1):

Change the word "localhost" to "127.0.0.1" and your mysql will no longer attempt to connect to the socket, but rather over TCP/IP.